# Meaning of TOOLCHAIN=$NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/windows

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ndk

I am trying to compile Ffmpeg on Android using Cygwin and windows 7. I came across these two options for the lines below when using some tutorials to make a .sh file for the compile. I am new to this process and am trying to understand what exactly to do. Is the prebuilt/windows referring to the package to the download packages as in the options in the image below or is it referring to the operating system I am using.

This was the first option I found:

```
TOOLCHAIN=$NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/windows-x86_64
```

This is the second option I found:

```
TOOLCHAIN=$NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86_64
```

This is the images of the package download options available on the Ffmpeg.org site that I thought it may be reffering to.

[image]

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The packages available for download from ffmpeg site have nothing to do with your toolchain. You can download a package that was built by somebody else for one of the supported platforms. You need a toolchain to build ffmpeg yourself. On Windows, you will install Android NDK and find the toolchain under `$NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/windows-x86_64`, not under `$NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86_64`.

Please be warned that building ffmpeg on Windows with Cygwin is a challenging task; you may find it easier to install Linux (maybe in a virtual machine), and build ffmpeg for Android using the Linux toolchain. The ffmpeg libraries produced this way can be freely used from Windows-based Android Studio.